# Why is alignof(max_align_t) 16?

Tags: c, memory-alignment, alignof

I'm running Debian on an x86_64 Intel processor.

gcc (Debian 8.3.0) compiles the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(){
  printf("%zd\n",alignof(max_align_t));
}
```

and outputs

```
16
```

What datatype requires a 16 byte alignment?

Comment: `__int128`. Also, it can perfectly be any arbitrary value AFAIK.

Comment: Frequently `long double`.

Comment: `max_align_t` is guaranteed to be "at least as large" as the largest type, not "exactly as large". So it could be 16 even if the largest datatype is only 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On x86_64, `_Alignof(long double)==16`.

Comment: unless [`-m96bit-long-double`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) is specified

Comment: @phuclv: That's contrary to the ABI and produces code that can't link with normal ABI-conforming x86_64 code.